# How to handle page loading scenarios where page loading icon displays randomly?

Tags: robotframework

I have clicked a  edit button in a webpage and verifying the page loading symbol which will not display all the times. Once page is loaded, loading symbol will get disappeared and my next screen will be displayed with Submit button.

Below script works, when page loading symbol is displayed after clicking the Edit button.

```
Click Element     ${EditButton}
${Status}=    Run Keyword And Return Status    Element Should Be Visible    ${Loading_Icon}
Run Keyword If    '${Status}'=='True'     Wait Until Keyword Succeeds     20s     1s    Element Should Not Be Visible      ${Loading_Icon}
Click Element    ${SubmitButton}
```

When page loading symbol is not displayed after clicking the Edit button, my script waits around 15 – 20 seconds and then it clicks Submit button. But, it should actually click Submit button immediately when loading icon is not displayed.

When I checked the log, the below line took 16 seconds to execute:

```
 ${Status}=    Run Keyword And Return Status    Element Should Be Visible    ${Loading_Icon}
```

Why is that it takes 16 seconds? Similar wait related script, increases the overall automation test execution time.

How to overcome it? Is there any alternate way to handle this page loading scenarios where loading icon displays randomly.

Comment: Have you set any wait timing, like implicit wait settings?

Comment: No, I have not set any wait.

Comment: @Kootstra  i tried simulating this scenario.When the expected element(i.e Loading icon in this case) is not all present, then it waits around 15 seconds.Do we have any alternate keyword instead of 'Run Keyword And Return Status' to get the status?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 ${Status}=    Run Keyword And Return Status    Element Should Be Visible    ${Loading_Icon}
```

In the above statement, reason for the waiting time is due to default timeout (i.e) 15 seconds. You can change it by adding implicit wait keyword before this line as below

```
${Orig_Wait}=    Set Selenium Implicit Wait    3 seconds
${Status}=    Run Keyword And Return Status    Element Should Be Visible    ${Loading_Icon}
Set Selenium Implicit Wait    ${Orig_Wait}
```

Above script performs the following:

Sets the implicit Wait time as 3 seconds. Now, status of the loading icon will be returned in 3 seconds instead of 15 seconds.Then, it sets back the default timeout

Answer (score 0):

Instead of waiting on the loading animation to disappear, try waiting for the submit button to appear. Something like this:

```
Click Element     ${EditButton}
Wait Until Page Contains Element    ${SubmitButton}    20s
Click Element    ${SubmitButton}
```

Hope this helps! :)